# Dispatcher is null when using useDispatch hook

Tags: reactjs, dispatch

I seem to be getting an error saying "dispatcher is null" when I attempt to use the useDispatch hook. I suspect the problem is coming from this component. See screenshots for detailed error information.

Can anyone spot why this is not working?

```html
import { Center, Wrap, WrapItem } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ProductCard from '../components/ProductCard';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getProducts } from '../redux/actions/productActions';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const ProductsScreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  const { loading, error, products } = productList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Wrap spacing="30px" justify="center" min-height="100vh">
      {products.map((product)=>(
        <WrapItem key={product._id}>
          <Center w="250px" h="550px">
            <ProductCard product={product}/>
          </Center>
        </WrapItem>
      ))}
    </Wrap>
  );
};

export default ProductsScreen;
```

[`[![enter image description here][1]][1]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLb1W.png)

[image]